# Is it possible to keep global variable `window.__TAURI__` after returning from authentication page?

Tags: rust, navigation, tauri

I'm using Tauri in a corporate setting with single sign-on. When I serve my webpage, it redirects to an authentication page and then forwards on to my original url.

I have `withGlobalTauri` set to `true`, but the `window.__TAURI__` object is deleted when returning from authentication.

I understand the `window` object is supposed to be cleared when loading new pages, but is it possible for tauri to reinject the global tauri variable on new page loads? and how?

Or is my only option to reload tauri as a module? as in:

```
import { invoke } from '@tauri-apps/api/tauri'
```

Answer (score 3):

I received an answer that

1. we don't inject the tauri api into external urls and I guess once you're outside the context you can't get into it (currently)
2. it's not clearly defined what's really expected when you navigate back to the tauri context
3. using the npm module instead of the global one is recommended anyway (smaller app size, better security)

So no, the global variable is not supposed to be retained, and it's better to use  as an import statement anyway.